# How does remember me cookie work with session life time?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm a bit confused with this,

Say the session has been started with default *php ini* settings where gc_maxlifetime is 1440 seconds. And i supposed to use remember me functionality with this, to which i set cookie lifetime as 14 days. As long as the session max life time set to 24 minutes which is obviously lesser than cookie life time (14 days), after 10 days (for example) the session likely (of course depends on *gc probability*) to be expired and would have no reference to the session id the remember me cookie has.

So how would setting a remember me cookie lifetime longer than the session lifetime remember/resume the session? or do i need to change the session max lifetime according to the cookie lifetime?

Comment: remember-me cookies CAN be tied to a particular session, but not necessarily. they can contain some completely different data, e.g. an encrypted user ID so that when the user returns and their previous session is done, the system can autologin them without ever showing a login prompt. directly tying a remember cookie to a session is generally not a good idea. you don't want stale sessions clogging up your system, especially if you have very long "remember me" periods set.

Comment: Do you mean that you are using the **remember me** to remember **session id**? AFAIK, **remember me** is used to store the 'username' when the user successfully logged-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a "remember me" cookie is a persistent cookie, not a session cookie.  It contains some encrypted information which allows an automatic login action to occur.  i.e. When there is no active session already, but the "remember me" cookie is present, then a new session will be started.

Answer (score 0):

The session GC function will delete session data (which is by default kept in plain text files), while the cookie settings will delete the cookie that keeps the session id.

In order for a session to be active, its data file, and a cookie with its ID must exist (AFAIK).